# Compiling cpp Project with command line But debugging in Vscode

Tags: c++, gdb, visual-studio-code

I compile my code with the command line. here is an example of how I compile a program named "out" with 2 libraries a and b

```
g++   -c -O3 -I../../include/boost_1_61_0 -std=c++14  -MMD  -MP -MF "a.o.d" -o a.o ../../my_Library/lib_a.cpp
g++  -c -O3  -I../../include/boost_1_61_0 -std=c++14  -MMD   -MP -MF  "b.o.d" -o b.o ../../my_Library/lib_b.cpp
g++ -lcurl -g -std=c++11 -lpthread    -o out a.o b.o -L../../include/shared_libraries -no-pie -lsqlite3 -lrt -lpthread -lcurl -fopenmp -lboost_serialization -lconfig++ -lpq -lstdc++ -lz -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lboost_program_options
```

In the end, I have that files (.o and .od) -  a, b, out
I want to debug a cpp file and b cpp file with Vscod how can I do this?

I know that I need to edit the tasks.json and launch.json But I don't know-how.
I use ubuntu.
thanks

I use ubuntu.

thanks

################# EDIT ###################

I did what Krzysztof Mochocki said. and after some minor changes, it works.

First, I remove the optimization flag from compiling line (-O3)

Second, I add -g (debug flag) to the compiling line.

```
g++   -c -g  -I../../include/boost_1_61_0 -std=c++14  -MMD -MP -MF "a.o.d"  -o a.o my_Librar/a.cpp
```

The last change is in launch.json in the field "program" I write there the program path, not the .o path

```
"program": "my/path/a",
```

And now I can debugging with Vscode.

thank you Krzysztof Mochocki

Comment: have you read the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)

Comment: if it statisfy You, can You mark my answer as solution, or do you have some doubts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example of configuration:

```
{
    "name": "(gdb) Launch my super program with 3 args",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "/home/user/build/my_program.o",
    "args": ["arg1", "--arg-2", "arg_3"],
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "cwd": "/home/user/build/workspace",
    "environment": [],
    "externalConsole": false,
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "setupCommands": [
        {
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        }
    ]
}
```

As I see on Your compile commands i am afraid it's not optimal. Try using some cmake, as you will add more files it will be much harder to maintain your compile commands.

Moreover your code is not debuggable, because you didn't add any debug info parameters. If you use cmake, it will add it automaticly after specyfing one parameter: `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`, so your example cmake for release would look like:

`cmake ../src`

and for debug:

`cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../src`